# Is it possible to synchronize publish status between translations?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Having 'Enable Translation' checked for a content type, is it possible to synchronize the publish status between all the translations in Drupal 8?

Comment: I think you mean you don't want to translate the publish status field?

Comment: Yes exactly, if one translation is disabled, I need the rest to be disabled too.

Comment: So you mean how to make the "Published" field not translatable, so it's the same for all translations?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control the translation configuration of base fields such as the publish status field from the content type configuraton, so go to

> Administration >> Configuration >> Regional and language >> Content
>   language

and uncheck the publish status field for your content type:

> [ - ]  Published

Now the publish option will be available only in the original language of the node and is then applied to all translations.

Comment: Great, that’s what I needed and I couldn’t find where to set it up. Thanks a lot @4k4