# Is there a hook for node after save?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

How do I unpublish translations when the english content is unpublished? I tried to unpublish the language content programmatically when I am unpublishing the english content in the `hook_node_update()` but it returns below error.

```
$languages = getLanguageList();
$currLanguage = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

if (!$node->status->value) {
    foreach ($languages as $languageId => $language) {
        if ($languageId != 'en' && $currLanguage == 'en') {
            if ($node->hasTranslation($languageId)) {
                $transNode = $node->getTranslation($languageId);
                $transNode->setPublished(false);
                $transNode->save();
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Error :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\EntityStorageException: "Update existing 'node' entity revision while changing the revision ID is not supported."
```

So I guess if I can do this after saving the node it would work. Is there a hook for node after save. Or is there a way to unpublish language contents of a node while unpublishing the source language(English)?

Comment: Yes, there is another option, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263414/is-it-possible-to-synchronize-publish-status-between-translations

Comment: @4k4 I need the unpublished/publish status for languages too. What I need to do is, I should be able to unpublish language content itself. And If I unpublish the source language content the translations should be unpublished too. If I unpublish a translation It shouldn't be affected to the source language

Comment: Yes, the linked option only works if you want to synchronize both ways. In your code checking the current language doesn't make much sense. Probably you want to check the node language to prevent recursion while saving the translations: `$node->language()->getId() == 'en'`?

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 you should use **hook_entity_update()**.
This hook runs once the entity storage has been updated.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/8.3.x

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this you are looking for:

Entity::postSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage, $update = TRUE)

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3ApostSave/8.6.x

Answer (score 2):

You could try in hook_pre_save so that should be before the main node has been effected

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.6.x

Comment: Can't update a translation while on the source language of the same node

Comment: `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update` happens after the DB submission

Comment: @Clive I tried my code with `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update` but it gave the same error as I mentioned